# PHP If mysql INSERTS record then refresh parent page from iframe

Tags: javascript, mysql, iframe, sql-insert, page-refresh

I have an iframe which submits data to the database using MYSQL (an insert query).  Is it possible to refresh the parent frame (not the iframe) if something is submitted to the database?

I was thinking it could possibly have an if statement that echos javascript if something is entered?

Thanks for any help. It's in PHP.

Comment: No you **can not** refresh window from an iframe. What you can do is to **detect in the parent when child has been submitted** but you can't use an iframe for this (plain Ajax). As alternative (in the parent) you have to **ask server** (in **polling**)) if any changed occurred (using a timestamp for last submit as seed, for example).

Answer (score -1):

javascript

```
  window.top.location.reload();
```